# How to read/open e-pub file in flutter android?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

[click to open image and see like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8OzX.jpg) Having solely developed Android applications I have decided to try crossplatform development, I have now open epub file.

Comment: The url_launcher or android_intent plugins should allow you to do that

Comment: Also worth checking out the [epub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/epub) package depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok....thank you, but i want to view of HtmlContent of chapter in that to bookmark, color, and underline of selected text. so any one kind of idea how it work ?please reply me on comment. sorry for miss type in english.

Comment: given above image link to provide same as in flutter using epub file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **epub_kitty** package - https://pub.dev/packages/epub_kitty

Answer (score 0):

epub_kitty doesnt seems to maintained anymore.
Check this one below.

https://github.com/JideGuru/epub_viewer